# Вывод файла с выделением самых коротких слов С++

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++, консоль

Подскажите, в чем ошибка, почему функция короткого слова не работает и как вставить выделение слов в тексте самых маленьких?

```
int ProvRazm();
int Vivodnaekran();
int SamKorotkSlov();

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    string buf;
    ifstream file("text.DAT"); /* Открываем файл */
    if (!file.is_open()) {     /* Проверяем файл */
        cerr << "Файла нет. Проверьте имя файла или его наличие!" << endl;
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }
    ProvRazm();
    Vivodnaekran();
    SamKorotkSlov();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int ProvRazm()
{
    FILE *in = fopen("text.DAT", "r"); // открытие потока
    // с параметром "только для чтения"
    int sum = 0;
    char buf[72];
    while (!feof(in))                  // проверка размеров текста
    {
        fgets(buf, 72, in);            // ф-ция коп. одной строки из файла
        if (strlen(buf) > 70)          // проверка длины строки
        {
            cout << "Размер строк слишком велик(не больше 70).\n";

        }
        sum += strlen(buf);            // ф-ция подсчета кол-ва символов в строке
    }
    if (sum > 1000) {
        cout << "Большое колличество символов (не больше 1000).\n";

    }
    fclose(in);                        // закрытие потока
    getchar();
    return sum;                        // возвращение кол-ва символов в файле
}


int Vivodnaekran()
{
    string buf;
    ifstream file("text.DAT");
    cout << "Содержимое файла:" << endl;
    while (getline(file, buf)) {
        cout << buf << endl;
    }
    return 1;
}

int SamKorotkSlov()
{
    char str[1000];
    // curlen - текущая длина слова
    // maxlen - максимальная длина слова
    // index - индекс, соответствующий позиции
    // конца самого длинного слова +1
    int curlen = 0, maxlen = 0, index = 0, i;
    ifstream file("text.DAT");
    for (i = 0;; i++) {
    if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0') {
        if (curlen > maxlen) {
        maxlen = curlen;
        index = i;
        }
        // если конец строки -> выйти из цикла
        if (str[i] == '\0')
        break;
        curlen = 0;
    } else
        curlen++;
    }
    cout << "" << maxlen << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: В вашей функции SamKorotkSlov() (по крайней мере в приведенном здесь коде) вообще нет ввода данных из файла в str[].

А зачем Вы файл много раз открываете и в разном стиле (то С++, то С)? Достаточно одного, потом его можно опять читать с начала.

--

Вообще-то (если считать, что слово ограничивается и концом строки) **достаточно одного прохода с чтением файла построчно.** Вместе с проверкой длины строки можно выбирать из нее слова и накапливать самые короткие (Вы понимаете, их может оказаться несколько) в массиве. 

В конце их можно распечатать из этого массива.

Что непонятно - спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял Вам надо найти слово с максимальной длиной, хотя по названию функции, с минимальной:) Вот пример для поиска с минимальной длиной:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    string buf;
    ifstream file("text.DAT"); /*Открываем файл*/
    if(!file.is_open())         /*Проверяем файл*/
    {
        cerr<<"Файла нету!!проверь имя файла!или его наличие!"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned int min = INT_MAX;
    string wordMinLength;
    while(file >> buf)
    {
        if (buf.length() < min)
        {
            wordMinLength = buf;
            min = buf.length();
        }
    }
    file.close();
    cout << min << " " << wordMinLength;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Для поиска с максимальной длиной измените строчку

```
unsigned int min = INT_MAX;
if (buf.length() < min)
```

на

```
unsigned int min = 0;
if (buf.length() > min)
```

Ну и переименуйте переменные для удобства чтения.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ПО ПОВОДУ ВЫДЕЛЕНИЯ**

Для выделения слов с минимальной длиной используйте функцию [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx). Например по следующему алгоритму: запоминаем длину минимального слова в тексте, затем выводим на консоль текст по одному слову (не забывая про знаки препинания и пробелы) и, если длина слова равна минимальной, то устанавливаем цвет текста, например, в красный, выводим слово, а затем возвращайте белый цвет. Примерно так:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

...

while (file >> buf)
{
   ...
   if (buf.length() == min) // Здесь еще можно проверять слово ли это, или знак препинания или служебный символ
   {
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12); // Устанавливаем красный
   }
   cout << buf; // Выводим слово
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 7); // Возвращаем белый
   ...
}
```

Comment: нет вы правы с минимальной длинной нужно найти, огромное вам спасибо за помощь, а как выделить эти слова в тексте, при нажатии любой кнопки я совсем не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: В тексте, в смысле в файле?

Comment: и он почему то маленькое слово ищет в одной строке, а как сделать во всем тексе, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вообще странно. У меня ищет во всем файле.

Comment: @Данил, (как я понимаю это Ваш ответ) а зачем **таким странным  ...|| min == -1) образом** искать минимум? 

Вообще максимумы-минимумы типов прописаны в <limits.h> и для int есть INT_MAX.

Вы берете unsigned min и присваивая ему -1 делаете его UINT_MAX. Таким образом любая длина слова (buf.length() и первого в т.ч.) будет меньше начального min (и все будет работать и без проверки на -1).

Comment: unsigned я добавил позже, после ругательства компилятора на несоответствие типов. А вообще да, мой косяк. Исправил

Comment: на экране когда текст выведен, он должен выделять

Comment: Обновил ответ